# Meaning of specific Code status/DNR levels

Tags: mimic-iii

I'm trying to understand the clinical meaning of two of the potential code status levels in the MIMIC3 data.

The six levels are:

1. Comfort Measures
2. CPR Not Indicated
3. Do Not Intubate
4. Do Not Resuscitate
5. Full Code
6. Other/Remarks

In particular, I'd like to know what CPR Not Indicated means and what Other/Remarks means.

CPR Not Indicated could mean:

1. "The patient chose to not have the caregivers use CPR, but intubation is ok."
2. "The patient chose to not have caregivers use CPR or intubation" and is functionally no different than DNR
3. "The caregiver has decided that this patient is not suitable candidate for CPR" (ie - a futility case)

Other/Remarks could mean:

1. "The patient has a complex case that cannot be coded. More info in the notes"
2. "We don't know the patient's code status."
3. Something else?

Does anyone know the correct interpretation of these code statuses?